# How to send the app request using php in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a app which i have registered in facebook. I want to add a option of sending app request to all my friends in facebook. I need to do it by authenticating and the asking the permission to continue to send all friends the app request. This i want to implement in php. Please help me friends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to do this using a 'Requests Dialog' which is available only through JavaScript. See below page for more information and examples of how to do this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible with the JavaScript popup, and there is a limit of how many requests you can send. Sending an app request to ALL your friends at once is considered spam anyway, you should never do this even if it would be possible.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

You can, of course, use the "to" parameter to specifiy the friends you want to send the request to:

```
function sendRequestToRecipients() {
 FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request',
    to: '499802820,499802852'
  }, requestCallback);
}
```