# Sending app-requests to users using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Everywhere I read, people say it is not possible to send out app-requests/notifications unless you use the Javascript SDK and another user actively chooses which friends to send invite to.

I'd like to send my users a notification - from my app - when they receive a new message from a user on my platform (if they enabled this feature). How is this possible?

I know it must be possible, since I often receive notifications from this app, I somehow once granted access:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reason for the downvote? I asking a honest question.

Answer (score 1):

App Requests seem to be only possible with the JavaScript SDK, see here: [How to send the app request using php in facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228643/how-to-send-the-app-request-using-php-in-facebook)

It makes sense, because it would be easy to spam a lot of users with the PHP SDK. More about App Requests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0

App Notifications on the other hand are possible with the PHP SDK, see the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

Keep in mind that Notifications are only possible to users who authorized your App, and they only work on Canvas or Page/Tab Apps. I assume that is what you get from the App in your screenshot.

Comment: I see. So I confused "apprequests" for being the same as App notifications - my bad. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah, apprequests = invitation to use an app. notifications = message to authorized user (for example: "you just got a new sheep in farmville").